# Use of \xs_IfStringCase_i doesn't match its definition?

Tags: color, xstring

I thought I had created a pretty straightforward command but apparently it's not allowed. I suspect I'd need to add `\expandafter` somewhere, but I'm not sure (where). I'd like to understand why in detail to learn. Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\getcolor}[1]{
    \IfStrEqCase{#1}{
        {r}{red}%
        {b}{blue}%
    }[#1]
}

\begin{document}

\getcolor{r} % prints 'red'

\getcolor{purple} % prints 'purple'

\textcolor{red}{text} % prints 'text' in red

\textcolor{\getcolor{r}}{text} % error

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big problem with your code, because `\IfStrEqCase` doesn't produce a color name, but the set of instructions to print it.

You can use an expandable test.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getcolor}{m}
  {
    \str_case:nnF { #1 }
      {
        {r}{red}
        {b}{blue}
      }
      {#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\getcolor{r} % prints 'red'

\getcolor{purple} % prints 'purple'

\textcolor{red}{text} % prints 'text' in red

\textcolor{\getcolor{r}}{text} % prints 'text' in red

\textcolor{\getcolor{purple}}{text} % prints 'text' in purple

\end{document}
```

[image]

If your LaTeX installation is not recent, you might get errors. In this case, add `\usepackage{xparse}`, but you should upgrade as soon as possible.

Please, don't use `minimal` for samples of code, it's not meant for this purpose.

Comment: Alright, I'm not familiar at all with the explicit syntax thing so I'll just copy+paste, works like a charm! I only kind of understand what you said about how it's returns an instruction, not a piece of text. And I read some stuff about the use of `minimal` and I guess I also sort of understand. So thanks for those three lessons!